# C# - Using two forms, access a variable from the first form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have been struggling with this for a week now and I don't see any other questions about it. I need to do something such as at [Accessing Forms data from another form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577732/accessing-forms-data-from-another-form) but I need to access a variable that is in the first form's code FROM the second form, and the click event happens during the second form.

Here is some of the first form's (mainForm's) code:

```
namespace Sudoku
{
    public partial class mainForm : Form
    {
        public mainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        difficultyForm difForm = new difficultyForm();
        public string difficulty = "";

        private void generateNewPuzzleMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            generateBegin();
        }

        private void generateBegin()
        {
            difForm.Show();
            difForm.difficultyTextBox.Text = "";
            difForm.difficultyTextBox.Focus();
```

And here is some of the second  form's (difficultyForm's) code:

```
namespace Sudoku
{
    public partial class difficultyForm : Form
    {
        string difficulty = "";

        public difficultyForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void enterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            difficulty = difficultyTextBox.Text;

            if (difficulty != "1" && difficulty != "2" && difficulty != "3" && difficulty != "4" && difficulty != "5")
                MessageBox.Show("The difficulty must be an integer from 1 to 5.", "Difficulty Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
            else
            {
                this.Hide();
            }
```

Also I am a noob at C# so if you have any other tips that would be great, thanks.

Note: I am using a string for difficulty because of something further down in the code, so please don't tell me to use an integer, thanks.

Comment: Do you want to get the value of a variable in the first form, or set it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing Forms data from another form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577732/accessing-forms-data-from-another-form)

Comment: Your main form should not be blanking out the text in the other form or setting the textbox's focus.  Those things should be done in the second form.  The textbox shouldn't even be exposed publicly.

Comment: I want to get a variable from the second form and set a variable in the first form equal to it so I can use it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To push information from your second form to your main form you should use an event.  Create the event on the second form and fire it when your button is clicked:

```
public partial class difficultyForm : Form
{
    string difficulty = "";

    public difficultyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event Action<string> DifficultySubmitted;

    private void enterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        difficulty = difficultyTextBox.Text;

        if (DifficultySubmitted != null)
            DifficultySubmitted(difficulty);

        //...
    }
}
```

Then subscribe to that event on the main form:

```
private void generateBegin()
{
    difForm.Show();
    difForm.difficultyTextBox.Text = "";
    difForm.difficultyTextBox.Focus();
    difForm.DifficultySubmitted += newDifficulty => difficulty = newDifficulty;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but difficulty (in the first form) did not seem to be set to the difficulty I entered on the second form. I assigned the value of difficulty to a text box on the first form and nothing appeared in the text box.

Comment: @Toje Did you set it in the event handler that is fired when the difficulty is submitted?  That would likely be the appropriate place to do so.

Comment: Sorry for the incoming noob question, but what is an event handler, exactly?

Comment: @Toje It's a method called when an event is fired.  In this case `newDifficulty => difficulty = newDifficulty;` is creating an anonymous method that is called when `DifficultySubmitted` is fired.

Comment: Okay, thank you, but how would I set difficulty in the event handler? (If you could post a reference or something that would be great; I could try and learn on my own, I've never worked with this stuff before - I mostly program in C++)

Comment: @Toje I am setting it in that event handler.  That's *exactly* what it's doing.

Comment: Are you setting it to newDifficulty? If so, how can I use newDifficulty? It gives me an error when I try anything in another line of code.

Comment: @Toje It's not setting the new difficulty, it's setting the old difficulty (`difficulty`) based on the value of the new difficulty.

Comment: Okay I understand more what is going on now. I have one last question.. what would the syntax be to call a function on the trigger of the event difficultySubmitted?

Comment: @Toje You call the function instead of setting the variable.  You can look up lambdas in C# for more information about them, or you can simply create a new named method instead of using an anonymous method and add that named method as the event handler.  Visual Studio will prompt you if you want to do this by default when you start adding an event handler.

Comment: Thank you, you have been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your difficulty correctly, you might want to look at event handling.

Define a custom event args class (eg: DifficultyEventArgs or something). Define a delegate with one param as your event args

Declare an event with the delegate in the class..

Invoke the delegate in the setter method of the property which you'd like to observe.

In the other form, you can subscribe to this event, to monitor any changes made to it. This is just one way.

Also, you should better use an enum for DifficultyLevel, instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the Form1 in a constructor param of DificultForm, and so access the controls of Form1

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to do is simply getting the value of your second forms's TextBox at an specific circunstance, you can create a public method in the second form's code

```
public string GetTxtBoxValue()
        {
            return difficultyTextBox.Text;
        }
```

and then call it from the first form.

But, if you want a better control upon it, I'd recommend using an event.